# Transformed content makes html stutter reaching the end of page

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a problem with a [reactjs project of mine.](https://auriga-diary.com/) It's about the mobile version. When you navigate to any picture and scroll down to the bottom - reaching the end, it stutters when you try to overscroll (only on mobile though).

I know why it is (tested my removing effect), but removing it isn't my desired solution. - I use an offset to create some kind of parallax applying `transform: translateY()`. Since it moves the content, I need to also change its margin to avoid unwanted spacing:

```
class Gallery extends Component {

    state = {
        offsetColRight: 0,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.changeOffset)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.changeOffset)
    }

    changeOffset = () => {
        const scroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0;

        this.setState({offsetColRight: scroll * -1 / 5})
    };

    render() {
        const style = {
            transform: 'translateY(' + this.state.offsetColRight + 'px)',
            marginBottom: this.state.offsetColRight + 'px'
        };

        return(
            <div className="p-gallery">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-6 px-0 p-animation">
                        <ColLeft images={this.props.gallery}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-6 px-0 p-animation" style={style}>
                        <ColRight images={this.props.gallery}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

How can I prevent it from stuttering on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the problem here is due to your event handler scroll happens to often and it causes your app is rendered often. You can first try to add throttle to reduce the how often it is executed.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
changeOffset = _.throttle(() => {
    const scroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0;

    this.setState({offsetColRight: scroll * -1 / 5})
}, 100);
```